# diamond inheritance of classes with same members in python and with super

Tags: python, inheritance, super, diamond-problem

I find myself in the strange situation of diamond inheritance, even worse is that the classes in the middle of the diamond share a member. Below I've shown a cut down piece of code which highlights my problem.

The method I used in writing classes I have learnt from http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ which is linked on the python documentation site for the built-in function `super`

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, z=None, **kwargs):
        self.z = z
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # super(B, self).__init__(z=z, **kwargs)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, z=None, **kwargs):
        self.z = z
        super(C, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class D(B, C):
    pass

d = D(z='y')

for arg, value in d.__dict__.iteritems():
    print arg, ':', value
```

which gives output

```
z : None
```

The problem is that the method of using keyword arguments to ensure the signatures of the functions match takes away the z argument from class C's init call. I can forcibly add the argument back into kwargs (see commented code) but then this results in me not being able to instantiate an object of type B since this will result in a call to the init of object which takes no parameters, this is a nice feature because it prevents me putting in invalid arguments when instantiating any of the below object.

Also I noticed that if I have the line super before I set the variables then the problem is fixed since the highest level object will overwrite the lower levels. However my code is heavily built around have the super at the end since all the actual "setting" is carried out by the low ever level classes whilst the higher level classes pass the value to be set down the chain of inheritance. Are there guidelines on where to fit in parent calls?

Any ideas Stackoverflow?

thanks

p.s. Is this just a bad design of 'cooperative classes'? What is a cooperative class exactly?are there rules or guidelines one should follow?

edit:

Stackoverflow won't let me answer my own question but I came up with a solution.

I don't think there should be ever any shared members between cooperative classes. If ever there are two classes which are independent of each other (in the sense there is no 'is a kind of' relationship) which share a member then you should add a level of abstraction into the inheritance relationship.

The shared member should be taken out and put into a separate class which inherits from a shared base class and is inherited from by the classes in the diamond.

Below is the corrected code. In keeping with the link in the OP I introduced a Root base class

I should point out I have had no formal programming education (like most here I guess) so apologies if I use wrong terminology.

```
class Root(object):
    pass

class A(Root):
    pass

class HasAZ(Root):
    def __init__(self, z=None, **kwargs):
        self.z = z
        super(HasAZ, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class B(HasAZ, A):
    pass


class C(HasAZ, A):
    pass

class D(B, C):
    pass

d = D(z='y')

for arg, value in d.__dict__.iteritems():
    print arg, ':', value
```

Comment: I can't see how you could make that work, given the fact that they share a member. If they share a member, they must have something else in common, can't you take that member and extract it into a common class?

Comment: thanks, that's what I did in the end. I obviously need to work on my OO thought processes

Comment: I feel like that's for the best =)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better way to do it but this should avoid the overwrite::

```
class C(A):
    def __init__(self, z=None, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(self, 'z'):
            self.z = z
        super(C, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks, I try to stay away from hasattr or anything that relies on getting methods/members using strings, seems more can go wrong that way? Also though I didn't mention it, but I use a lot of set methods in the __init__ which need to be able to overwrite methods later in the code

Answer (score 1):

> Is this just a bad design of 'cooperative classes'?

Yes, specifically because of the attribute collision.  If you didn't have the attribute the same name it wouldn't be a problem in so far a `B.z` wouldn't be overwritten by `C.z`.

> What is a cooperative class exactly?are there rules or guidelines one should follow?

The one you already read:

http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

As far as I know that is the best source for the rules/guidelines for cooperative classes.

You have a choice to make.  You can:

- make your attribute names unique across all classes in the inheritance tree

or

- always pass all the arguments down the tree.   At that point you might as well change all the signatures to `__init__(self, **kwargs)`

or

- don't use multiple inheritance