# Proper use of Python inheritance super and __init__ of class decorator, decorating classes

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, decorator, multiple-inheritance, init

I have several classes that are inheriting from a base Widget class from a third-party package.  I have two separate set of behaviors that I want to optionally apply to some of these classes (one, the other, or both).  Setting this behavior up with classic/standard inheritance would result in a inheritance diamond:

```
class NotMyWidget:
  pass

class OptionalBehavior1(NotMyWidget):
  pass

class OptionalBehavior2(NotMyWidget):
  pass

class MySpecialWidget(OptionalBehavior1, OptionalBehavior2)
  pass

class MySpecialWidget2(OptionalBehavior2):
  pass
```

Maybe I'm being dumb, and this is actually the preferred solution, and the diamond isn't actually an issue.

I need to figure out a good implementation in Python 2.7.5 (forced by other packages that depend on it and RedHat 7 and have not been fixed for Python 3, I wish I had a choice here).

For my own edification, I'd like to see Python 3 solutions as well.

What I have tried, using the decorator concept:

```
import functools

class NotMyWidget:
  def __init__(self, parent):
    pass

def optional_behavior1(cls):
  if not issubclass(cls, NotMyWidget):
    raise TypeError('Decorated class must inherit from NotMyWidget')

  @functools.wraps(cls, updated=())
  class Optional1(cls):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(Optional1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      #special init needs of optional_behavior1 here

    #define overloaded methods here to modify NotMyWidget base behavior
  return Optional1

def optional_behavior2(cls):
  if not issubclass(cls, NotMyWidget):
    raise TypeError('Decorated class must inherit from NotMyWidget')

  @functools.wraps(cls, updated=())
  class Optional2(cls):
    def __init__(self, parent, second_arg, *args, **kwargs):
      super(Optional2, self).__init__(parent, second_arg, *args, **kwargs)
      #special init needs of optional_behavior2 here, including logic based off of second_arg

    #define overloaded methods here to modify NotMyWidget base behavior and MySpecialWidget* behavior (second_arg)
  return Optional2

@optional_behavior2
@optional_behavior1
class MySpecialWidget(NotMyWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent, second_arg, third_arg):

    #attempt 1
    super(MySpecialWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    # -> TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

    #attempt 2
    super(MySpecialWidget, self).__init__(parent, second_arg, third_arg)
    # -> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object (Optional2 __init__ run once, Optional1 __init__ run recursively until exception thrown, reversing decorators reverses which class is called once or until error)

    #attempt 3
    #no super/__init__ invocation included
    # -> RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type MySpecialWidget was never called

    #attempt 4
    #no super/__init__ invocation included here
    #call to super(cls, self).__init__(parent) in both __init__ methods of Optional1 and Optional2, before their own super/__init__ invocations
    # -> TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

    #attempt 5
    #no super/__init__ invocation included here
    #call to super(cls, self).__init__(<same args as Optional1 or Optional2 super/__init__ invocation) in __init__ method of Optional1 and Optional2, before their own super/__init__ invocations
    # -> RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type MySpecialWidget was never called
```

I had some variant of atempt 4 or 5 that inexplicably seemed to work, but I thought it was extremely odd to not have a super/**init** call in the **init** method of MySpecialWidget, so I jumped back down the rabbit hole and have not seen a functioning verison since.  I'm obvioulsy misunderstanding the behavior of Python inheritance and super/**init**.

Comment: Note that you are showing an old style class, which behaves subtly different from Python 2 new style classes or Python 3 classes. Is this intentional?

Comment: Absolutely not.  I have spent most of my OOP time in Python using Python 3.  I completely forgot that Python 2 had two implementations of classes.  Is there a specific difference that I am running straight into?  I defined NotMyWidget in my code snippets above, but those are actually defined in a separate package (PyQt4 QWidget).  I'd guess that they are likely of the new style class variety, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I've just double-checked and `super` fails for old-style classes. So if it's working for you, you have a new-style class. Changing `class NotMyWidget:` to `class NotMyWidget(object):` should be enough for the MRE.

Comment: @t0w0i7ne I updated my answer to explain the recursion caused by using decorators and the pythonic way to solve it and the alternative way to solve it if the pythonic way isn't available.

Comment: @t0w0i7ne If the answer I've given isn't sufficient, could you please let us know what other information you still need? If it's a bit unrelated to the original question/bounty, I'd recommend opening up another question.

Answer (score 2):

## Use Diamond Inheritance

I believe diamond inheritance, which is a form of multiple inheritance, is definitely the preferred solution here because using decorators on classes can add more complexity to your code. Unless your issue is actually more complicated and diamond inheritance doesn't work for you, inheritance should do the trick. [You can also check out this StackOverflow answer for more on how to handle diamond inheritance.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404520/4709300)

```py
class Widget():
  def __init__(self, parent):
    pass

class BehaviorA(Widget):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(BehaviorA, self).__init__(parent)
    # Do stuff here
  # Maybe add methods or properties here

class BehaviorB(Widget):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(BehaviorB, self).__init__(parent)
    # Do stuff here
  # Maybe add methods or properties here
  # Make sure not to use names that conflict with BehaviorA

class MyWidget(BehaviorA, BehaviorB):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(MyWidget, self).__init__(self, parent)
    # Do stuff here
```

The execution order for this diamond is pretty simple. If you were to call `print` in all of the `__init__` methods, you would see the following order:

- `MyWidget`
- `BehaviorB` (the reason why B runs before A is that B was inherited last and inheritance is kind of like a stack)
- `BehaviorA`
- `Widget`

If you're ever confused about the order of where Python will look for methods first, you can look at `MyWidget.__mro__`.

### Why the infinite recursion when using decorators?

The reason why you get infinite recursion is that you're using decorators to create a new class and also using the old `super(ClassName, self).__init__(...)` syntax together.

```py
class Widget():
  def __init__(self, parent):
    pass

def behavior_a(cls):
  class BehaviorA(cls):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(BehaviorA, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  return BehaviorA

@behavior_a
class MyWidget(Widget):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent) # This is where we hit infinite recursion becuase MyWidget is now actually BehaviorA

MyWidget('test') # Infinite Recursion
```

What's happening is that you're replacing the value of `MyWidget` with the class generated by the decorator, `BehaviorA`; therefore, when you run `super(MyWidget, self)` you're getting back the parent class of `BehaviorA` which is the original `MyWidget`. From there, you call `__init__` on the original `MyWidget`, and the loop repeats.

To avoid this problem, you can either use the newer `super()` syntax if it's available, or you can use `Widget.__init__` directly since you have a single inheritance scheme when using these decorators. The most pythonic way would be to use the newer `super()` syntax.

```py
@behavior_a
@behavior_b
class MyWidget(Widget):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__(parent)

# or

@behavior_a
@behavior_b
class MyWidget(Widget):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    Widget.__init__(self, parent)
```

Comment: The two behaviors need a different number of arguments.  Will this still work in the example above?  One of the optional behaviors only needs the parent argument (only to call Widget.__init__ via super), while the other optional behavior requires two more arguments.  How would this impact the super/__init__ call in MyWidget?

I thought that the functools.wraps was going to keep the class naming in check from the decoration, but it must not do that.

I cannot use the newer super() syntax in my actual use case (stuck on 2.7.5), but I will keep that in mind for future needs.

Comment: My browser didn't show all of your edits before I finished commenting.  Your direct call to Widget.__init__ seems to answer my question above.

Comment: @t0w0i7ne Could you accept my answer since it answered your question, please.